# Combobox in sap.ui.table.Table

Tags: sapui5

I want to set values in a Combobox in the table: It does not show me the values ? Here is the code: 
View:

```
<Column width="10rem">
    <m:Label text="{i18n>Status}" />
    <template>
        <m:ComboBox items="{items>/Status}"
                 templateShareable="true">
            <m:items>
                <core:Item text="{Name}" />
            </m:items>
        </m:ComboBox>
    </template>
</Column>
```

Controller: This is the parameterset.

```
success : function(oData, oResponse) {
                      // create JSON model
                      var oODataJSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                      var child1 = [];
                      child1.push({Name:"S"});
                      child1.push({Name:"E"});
                      oData.Status = child1;
                      oODataJSONModel.setData(oData);
                      oView.setModel(oODataJSONModel, "items");
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing alias for model in property binding of `Item`.

```
<core:Item text="{items>Name}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, now in the console the following error appears:  `During a clone operation, a template was found that neither was marked with 'templateShareable:true' nor 'templateShareable:false'` Do you know what is wrong ?

Comment: ANother question: When I want to get the line with `this.getView().getModel("items").getProperty(
          oTable.getContextByIndex(aSelectedItems[0]).sPath).Status`; But it just show "false" and not "E". Why ?

Comment: it`s about memory leaks - details here: https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/understanding-templateShareable-in-sapui5

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to read the entity, when the Item of the comboboy is changed ?

Comment: @Mario Please, accept this answer to inform others that your original issue is solved now. About the `templateShareable`, this might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47734086/5846045. Regarding your ["Another question"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804733/combobox-in-sap-ui-table-table/41804923#comment70799633_41804923), please open a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead of asking it in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the value of the combobox when it changes you can do the following. First in the XML, set the property `selectionChange="nameOfYourFunction"` in the combobox element. Whenever the user clicks on a different item, `nameOfYourFunction()` will execute. Here in this function you can check for the value.

```
nameOfYourFunction : function(){
     //Do whatever you want to do here when user changes value of combo
     this.getView().byId("combobox_id_here").getValue(); // returns text inside combobox
}
```

You might have to play around with the function and see when *exactly* it gets called. I have done a little with it and sometimes it gets called twice. I think once when the Combobox's text is a value in the list and then it gets called again when you leave focus of the combobox. Getting called twice probably won't affect your code though, depends on what you do in your function.