# Shared Template Must Be Marked with templateShareable:true Error

Tags: sapui5

I am creating an application with SAPUI5 (I am new with this library) and I run to the following strange error:

> A shared template must be marked with templateShareable:true in the binding info -

Codewise, the cause is to be found in `cartelleDisponibili: cartelleObtained` inside the following Promise:

```
new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject) {
    cartellaData.results.forEach((cartella, index) => {
      oModel.read("/SheetSet", {
        filters: [
          new sap.ui.model.Filter("ZUSERNAME", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, userData.Username),
          new sap.ui.model.Filter("ZTYPE", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, 'P'),
          new sap.ui.model.Filter("ZCARTELLA", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, cartella.ZCARTELLA),
        ],
        success: function(sheetData){
          var sheetsResults = [];
          for(var sheet = 0; sheet < sheetData.results.length; sheet++){
            sheetsResults.push({
              "Sheet": sheetData.results[sheet].ZSHEET,
              "CanWrite": sheetData.results[sheet].ZCANWRITE ? true : false, 
            });
          }
          cartelle.push({
            "Cartella": cartella.ZCARTELLA,
            "CanWrite": cartella.ZCANWRITE ? true : false,
            "Sheets": sheetsResults,
          });
        },
        error: function(oEvent) {}
      });
    });
  resolve(cartelle);
}).then(function(cartelleObtained) {
  var selectedUser = {
    title: `Utente ${userData.Username}`,
    editUsername: false,
    progNavi: false,
    progProd: true,
    userMainCredentials: {
      userName: userData.Username,
      type: "P",
      isEnabled: userData.isAbilitato,
      isAdmin: userData.isAdmin,
      firstName: userData.Nome,
      lastName: userData.Cognome,
    },
    cartelleDisponibili: cartelleObtained,
  };
  var oJSONModelNewUser = new JSONModel(selectedUser);
  _this.getView().setModel(oJSONModelNewUser, "userModel");
  if (!_this._dShowUser) {
    _this._dShowUser = sap.ui.xmlfragment("cabot.ui.wt.fragment.ShowUser", _this);
    _this.getView().addDependent(_this._dShowUser);
  }
  _this._dShowUser.open();
});
```

If I pass to `cartelleDisponibili` an array of items directly, the error is not thrown. I need to fix this issue also because this is causing some little odd behavior in the UI. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PlanningCalendar templateShareable Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362359/planningcalendar-templateshareable-error)

Answer (score 2):

You must be using an old version of UI5. At least, the error message is not part of the source code anymore [since 1.38](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/0c21e93acb4998350a4639d2dc508bc8d62664c3). The improved error message says a bit more:

> During a clone operation, a template was found that neither was marked with 'templateShareable:true' nor 'templateShareable:false'. The framework won't destroy the template. This could cause errors (e.g. duplicate IDs) or memory leaks.

This indicates that, somewhere, you also must be defining an aggregation binding inside a control which is used as a template for another aggregation binding in an upper hierarchy level.

There are two solutions to get rid of the error message (depending on what you want):

- If you want to have more control over the lifecycle of your template control(s), enable `templateShareable` (with value `true`) explicitly in each [aggregation binding info object](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/bindAggregation).
- However, if you do not take care of such templates by yourself, let UI5 handle them by explicitly disabling `templateShareable` (with value `false`) in each aggregation binding info object.

For more information, take a look at the documentation [Lifecycle of Binding Templates](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3a4a9e562988456c9be0ef883ae7da50) and at [this blog post](https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/understanding-templateShareable-in-sapui5) by [Nabi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276826/nabi).