# Aggregation Binding: How to Put Different Control with Different Aggregation Binding inside the Control which Already Has Aggregation Binding

Tags: sapui5

I have the following data in my model:

```
{
  vertexTable: [
    {
      "NAME": "Tethys",
      "TYPE":"titan",
      "RESIDENCE":"Othrys"
    },
    {
      "NAME": "Oceanus",
      "TYPE": "titan",
      "RESIDENCE": "Othrys"
    }
  ],
  vertexAttributes: [
    {
      "COLUMN_NAME": "NAME",
      "DATA_TYPE_NAME": "VARCHAR"
    },
    {
      "COLUMN_NAME": "TYPE",
      "DATA_TYPE_NAME": "VARCHAR"
    },
    {
      "COLUMN_NAME": "RESIDENCE",
      "DATA_TYPE_NAME": "VARCHAR"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to display this data in my view such that there is a label coming from `vertexAttributes/COLUMN_NAME` and each label has an associated dropdown / select box coming from ..

- `vertexTable/NAME` for the *NAME* label,
- `vertexTable/TYPE` for the *TYPE* label, and
- `vertexTable/RESIDENCE` for the *RESIDENCE* label.

I thought about using a Form control which has aggregation binding to `formElements="{/vertexattributes}"` and then each Form Element bound to `"{COLUMN_NAME}"` from `vertexAttributes`. But now, I want to put the Select control which has an aggregation binding to `vertexTable` and then the items bound to `NAME`, `TYPE`, and `RESIDENCE`.

Below is the code I tried in my view:

```
<f:form>
  <f:FormContainer formElements="{/vertexAttributes}">
    <f:FormElement label="{COLUMN_NAME}">
      <List id="values" items="{path: 'VALUES', templateShareable: false}">
        <StandardListItem title="{value}"></StandardListItem>
      </List>
    </f:FormElement>
  </f:FormContainer>
</f:form>
```

I had to use `templateShareable` because I was getting an error. Not completely sure what it is.
Also, instead of select / dropdown, I am using a List to show the complete values.

[image: Output]

Is this the right way to do it or is there a better way?
I came across factory function but I am unable to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "sap/ui/layout/form/FormElement",
  "sap/m/Label",
  "sap/m/Select",
  "sap/ui/core/Item",
], (JSONModel, FormElement, Label, Select, Item) => sap.ui.xmlview({

  viewContent: `<mvc:View
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="demo.MyController"
  >
    <form:Form editable="true">
      <form:layout>
        <form:ResponsiveGridLayout/>
      </form:layout>
      <form:FormContainer
        formElements="{
          path: '/vertexAttributes',
          factory: '.createFormElement'
        }"
      />
    </form:Form>
  </mvc:View>`,

  controller: sap.ui.controller("demo.MyController", {
    createFormElement: function(id, context) {
      const columnName = context.getProperty("COLUMN_NAME");
      return new FormElement(id).setLabel(new Label({
        text: columnName,
      })).addField(new Select().bindItems({
        path: "/vertexTable",
        template: new Item().bindProperty("text", columnName),
      }));
    },
  }),

}).setModel(new JSONModel({
  vertexTable: [{
      "NAME": "Tethys",
      "TYPE": "Titan1",
      "RESIDENCE": "Othrys1"
    },
    {
      "NAME": "Oceanus",
      "TYPE": "Titan2",
      "RESIDENCE": "Othrys2"
    },
  ],
  vertexAttributes: [{
      "COLUMN_NAME": "NAME",
      "DATA_TYPE_NAME": "VARCHAR"
    },
    {
      "COLUMN_NAME": "TYPE",
      "DATA_TYPE_NAME": "VARCHAR"
    },
    {
      "COLUMN_NAME": "RESIDENCE",
      "DATA_TYPE_NAME": "VARCHAR"
    },
  ]
})).placeAt("content")));
```

```html
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.layout, sap.m, sap.ui.core"
  data-sap-ui-preload="async"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
  data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-resourceRoots='{"demo": "./"}'
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitForTheme="true"></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

The design of your data structure is somewhat questionable. The fact that the value (of `vertexAttributes/COLUMN_NAME`) is the key (of `vertexTable/*`) in other objects makes the implementation complicated. Nevertheless, as you've already tried before, displaying the appropriate data is still possible with a factory function.

The example above creates a Select control in each iteration of the `createFormElement` call. Then, the select item can bind its text with the current `columnName` as a path.

---

About the `templateShareable`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47734086/5846045

Comment: value of vertexAttributes/Column_Name is not the key of vertexTable it refers to all the columns headers in the vertex table.
My vertex Table looks like below:

`NAME       |  TYPE    |   RESIDENCE 

Oceanus   |  titan       |   Orthys

Tethty        |  titan       |   Orthys`

So the idea was to display the labels are column headers and the list as the associated values in the column.

Thank you for the response I was unable to get the factory function running. I will try your solution out. :) And also thank you for templateShareable link.